Upper-triangular pre-conditioning for Jacobi convergence
I am interested in analyzing convergence of the Jacobi method to solve the linear system $Ax=b$,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1   \\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1   \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, we write $A=D-E-F$, with $D=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, E=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -4 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, F= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and the iteration takes the form
$$x^{(k+1)}=Bx^{(k)}+ f, x^{(0)}\in\mathbb{R}^2,$$
with
$$B=D^{-1}(E+F)= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2 \\-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, f=D^{-1}b=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
We find that the e-values of $B$ are $\pm\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the spectral radius of $B$ is $\sqrt{2}>1$, and the Jacobi method does not converge.
A question I am trying to answers asks whether diagonal or upper-triangular preconditioning will make the method convergent. I know that diagonal will not work, but I am not sure what upper-triangular pre-conditioning is, and I could not find its definition in my textbook. So my question is what is such a preconditioning technique and will it make this iteration convergent? I'm under the impression that preconditioning only changes the rate of convergence of a method and not its actual convergence, but I welcome any correction.

That makes sense. For terminology's sake, is this considered "upper-triangular preconditioning"?
